# Schedule a task to run as soon as browser repaint

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is there any way to schedule a task (macrotask, microtask or whatever) and make sure it will be executed upon browser repaint?

I know about `requestAnimationFrame (rAF)`, the browser will call a task scheduled by the rAF before repainting so, it is not appropriate here

Comment: Could you explain more what you are trying to accomplish and why you need this step?

Comment: I would like to run an animation function as soon as some DOM elements got repainted by browser

Comment: It would really help a lot if you could make a more clear picture of your use case and why this is something that you want, because there isn't an API that does this. But maybe there is a different solution for your situation.